How do I know I can make these inferences across separate categorical rows?
I'm studying very basic statistics, starting with two-way frequency tables. However, I have tons of uncertainty around this because there's a lot of...assumptions that seem to be made, but never explained.
Attached is a PNG of a question

Based on this table, it "seems" accurate...ish...to suggest Italian people are "more likely" to have Brown or hazel eyes.
But why am I allowed to compare two completely different categories? Don't I need to pay attention to the sample size? Don't I need to know if the samples are random? Don't I need to know what percentage have dual citizenship? How am I allowed to take two completely separate row-frequencies, and then compare them?

You need a table of the counts behind these percentages!

First, you need the counts, not the proportions. So your first intuition "Don't I need to pay attention to the sample size?" is correct. If these proportions were derived from just 15 subjects (5 per "origin"), the proportions would mean nothing; could be due to "dumb luck", i;.e sampling variations. But if it came from 300 subjects (100 per origin), your intuition that "Italian people are "more likely" to have Brown or hazel eyes" would be right on.
Now, if you lay this out as you did, but with counts, you have a 3x3 contingency matrix (or table) (see wiki). That can be tested via Fisher exact, or chi square test, whch will take sample sizes into account.
You also ask "Don't I need to know if the samples are random?". Yes, you do. But that has nothing to do with how you analyze the data. It has to do with the sampling. If all your Italian subjects came from just 3 families, yes, your sample is biased, and any conclusion will be biased (basically, you are wasting your time, and anybody else's trying to analyze the data). Same if your Italian sample came only from Sicily (there are a lot of blue eyed blonds in northern Italy).  You have to trust that the sample is random, and representative. If this is not the case, all bets are off.
You also ask "Don't I need to know what percentage have dual citizenship?". This is amusing, and still on point. But it still comes down to how good the sampling was. If you sampled all the German subjects from a Turkish neighborhood (there is a large Turkish sub-population now in Germany, with German passports), or sampled all the English subjects from an Indian neighboorhood (Rishi Sunak?) (all these are called "sample of convenience"), your sample will be biased. So yes, these are all subtle details to be given careful considerations when sampling.
Now, in most published papers, the sampling is given very short shrift (often, all you get is "random"), and most of the paper is devoted to the analysis, the results, etc. And if indeed the sampling was not representative (e.g. sampling of convenience), or not i.i.d. (independent, identically distributed), then the analysis and the results are not worth the ink they are printed with...
Now, in the real world, all samples are conducted on "volunteers" (we can not coherce a subject to be part of our study). Many are samples of convenience (patients from a given hospital, subjects from a given student population, etc.). So one could argue that truly representative, and truly independent is very difficult to achieve in the real world.
So what do we do? 1) We cross our fingers that our samples are not too biased 2) Much more importantly, we rely on science's magic weapon, reproducibility (aka falsification). If colleagues, using their own sample, with its own bias, reproduce our result, we may have been onto something. Otherwise??? 3) Some studies (e.g Covid vaccines) have such huge sample sizes (100,000's), spread over multiple locations, accross many age groups and demographics, etc., that the doubts that you raise may be put aside.
But yes, your analysis coming out is only as good as your data going in: the good old GIGO (gargabe in, garbage out).

re:coercing people, mandatory surveys are definitely a thing, even though it's certainly not the case in the situation described in the question.

The Tuskegee syphilis study was coercive.  This led to laws regulating research involving human participants, the creation of IRB's, ertc. You probably think of a census, which is mandatory. But a census is not "research".  There are exceptions for research, but they are few and far between. And in pretty much all cases, one needs consent at a bare minimum (and rightly so).

Not censuses, really surveys (e.g. https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-manuals-and-guidelines/-/ks-02-18-240), and not necessarily conducted by national statistical institutes, but research institutions or institutions to which the surveyed individuals belong to. Besides, social science researchers request all the time access to data collected from mandatory surveys (that's why you have things like this https://www.casd.eu/en/), so it is not uncommon to have individuals coerced to answer surveys that will be used for research purposes.

Hummm. This paper (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8734125/) claims that "Participation in the study was voluntary. The participants and/or their parents/legal guardians were also informed about the aims and contents of the study, and about data protection."., and "informed consent was obtained in writing or electronically." I strongly doubt that it is ethical, or legal, to coerce individuals to answer any survey... This is why ethics boards exist. Obtaining informed consent, and ensuring it is voluntary has some, but rare exceptions ; EHIS is not one of them.

Ah, good catch. Still, mandatory surveys are not uncommon. As I understand you speak French, here is an example of a mandatory victimization survey, conducted on 200,000 people: https://mobile.interieur.gouv.fr/Interstats/L-enquete-Vecu-et-ressenti-en-matiere-de-securite-VRS . And another one directed toward 40,000 companies and nonprofits: https://www.francecompetences.fr/fiche/lancement-de-la-6eme-edition-de-lenquete-europeenne-sur-la-formation-professionnelle-continue/ . I could list many examples like that, but some googling will show you that mandatory surveys are not uncommon at all.

(cont'd) Definitely very regulated in democratic countries, in particular in Europe, but they still do exist, and there are quite a few. We may consider them as unethical, but my point here is that they do exist.

Thanks for the link. Indeed, the 2 studies are "obligatoire". As I said there can be some exceptions (but rare). These 2 in particular are "governmenta;" studies, and there became mandatory only after review by a review council, and fater legal decree. Not your typical research study...  L'exception qui confirme la regle?
